# Плавность анимации при разных @keyframes

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Всем привет! 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать "плавность" анимации.

У меня есть @keyframes, который описывает поведение анимации при загрузки. 
А при ховере, подключается другой `@keyframes` (анимация и ее ход меняется).

Между их сменой происходит резкость.

Вот пример резкости http://jsfiddle.net/g4wvqrL8/

Вопрос: как при разных `@keyframes` при ховере сделать плавную смену 2х типов анимация?

Пробовала делать transition (смещала их на нужную траекторию при ховере и начинать новую анимацию, но плавность все равно не было).

Или же как начинать анимацию с места, где остановилась анимация до этого??

Подскажите , всем заранее спасибо!

```css
.icon-1 {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 85px auto;
  animation: pull 3s infinite reverse ease-in-out
}

.icons {
  width:80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:90px;
}

.icons:hover {
  animation: rotate360 4s infinite reverse cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1);
}

@keyframes pull {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50%   {
    transform: translateY(-55px);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }  
}

@keyframes rotate360 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(30px);  
  }
  100%   {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <div class="icon-1">    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 70 76">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#red_box_on_v"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>    
<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <g id="red_box_on_v">
      <g>
        <polygon fill="#ED1C24" points="70,18 70,62 30.8,76 0.1,14"></polygon>
      </g>
      <g>
        <polygon fill="#C91D23" points="30.8,76 0,58.8 0.1,14 31,31.4"></polygon>
      </g>
      <g>
        <polygon fill="#A01D22" points="31,31.4 0.1,14 39.2,0.7 70,18"></polygon>
      </g>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, отловить конец итерации анимации и потом ее отключить. 
Возможно вам нужно подправить размеры контейнеров, так как при вращении мышь сходит с контейнера.

http://jsfiddle.net/g4wvqrL8/3/

```js
$(function() {

  function whichTransitionEvent() {
    var t,
      el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

    var transitions = {
      "transition": "animationiteration",
      "OTransition": "oanimationiterationd",
      "WebkitTransition": "webkitAnimationIteration"
    }

    for (t in transitions) {
      if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
        return transitions[t];
      }
    }
  }

  var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();
  var $icons = $(".icons"),
    $icon1 = $(".icon-1");


  $icons.hover(
    function() {
      var self = $(this);
      $icon1.addClass("pause");
      $icons.addClass("animate-rotate");
    }, function() {
      $icons.one(transitionEvent, function(event) {
        $icons.removeClass("animate-rotate");
        $icon1.removeClass("pause");
      });
    }
  );


});
```

```css
.icon-1 {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 85px auto;
  animation: pull 3s infinite reverse ease-in-out
}
.icons {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 90px;
}
.pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
.animate-rotate {
  animation: rotate360 4s infinite reverse forwards cubic-bezier(0.1, 0, 1, 1);
}
@keyframes pull {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-55px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate360 {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icons">
  <div class="icon-1">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 70 76">
      <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#red_box_on_v"></use>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <g id="red_box_on_v">
      <g>
        <polygon fill="#ED1C24" points="70,18 70,62 30.8,76 0.1,14   "></polygon>
      </g>
      <g>
        <polygon fill="#C91D23" points="30.8,76 0,58.8 0.1,14 31,31.4   "></polygon>
      </g>
      <g>
        <polygon fill="#A01D22" points="31,31.4 0.1,14 39.2,0.7 70,18   "></polygon>
      </g>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

все дело в смещении

```
@keyframes rotate360 {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(0px);        
    }
    100%   {
        transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(0px);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g4wvqrL8/2/

Comment: Да, это понятно, спасибо. Тут можно переписать, чтобы не было смещения. А как сделать, чтобы когда hover пропал, анимация закончила свое выполнение? и только потом стала та анимация, которая отрабатывает не по hover

Comment: думаю без js тут не обойтись, можно было бы использовать `delay` в `animation`, но толку от него, если `:hover` пропадает..

можно повесить эффект не на `:hover`, а на класс, который будет висеть время, равное длительности самой анимации